# Stripe:: Cannot charge a customer that has no active card in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, stripe-payments

everyone I'm trying to implement stripe in my laravel application I have gone through Cartlyst docx and setup it was mentioned but there when I am requesting for testing payment I'm getting this error `Cannot charge a customer that has no active card` I have looked into google but nothing worked for me till now.

here is the code

```
public function payment(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make(
        array(
            'tokenId' => $request->tokenId,
        ),
        array(
            'tokenId' => 'required',
        )
    );
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $errors = $validator->errors();
        if ($errors->first('tokenId')) {
            $message = $errors->first('tokenId');
        } else {
            $message = __('apiMessages.parametersRequired');
        }
        $this->setMeta("422", $message);
        return response()->json($this->setResponse());
    }
    try{

        $stripe = Stripe::make(env('STRIPE_SECRET'), Constant::STRIPE_VERSION);
        $tokenId= $request->tokenId;
        $customer = $stripe->customers()->create([
            'email' => 'patrick@gmail.com',
        ]);
        /*$customer = $stripe->customers()->find($tokenId);*/
        $stripeCustomerId= $customer['id'];
        $charge = $stripe->charges()->create([
            'customer' => $stripeCustomerId,
            'currency' => 'USD',
            'amount'   => Constant::AMOUNT,
        ]);
        $chargeId=$charge['id'];
        $payment= new Payment();
        $payment->userId=1;
        $payment->amount= Constant::AMOUNT;
        $payment->chargeId= $chargeId;
        $payment->paymentStatus= 1;
        $payment->save();
        $this->setMeta("200", __('apiMessages.paymentSuccess'));
        return response()->json($this->setResponse());
    }
    catch (StripeException $stripeException)
    {
        $this->setMeta("403", $stripeException->getMessage());
        return response()->json($this->setResponse());
    }
}
```

Please enlighten me where I am wrong?

Comment: anybody here...?

Comment: Well, the error is quite clear, the card is not active, activate the customer card.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes thanks to [jycr753](https://stackoverflow.com/users/930306/jycr753) for enlighten me about my mistake. I have not created any card instant thats why got this error

```
$stripeCustomerId= $customer['id'];
        $card = $stripe->cards()->create($stripeCustomerId, $request->tokenId); // add this to add a card.
        $charge = $stripe->charges()->create([
            'customer' => $stripeCustomerId,
            'currency' => 'USD',
            'amount'   => Constant::AMOUNT,
        ]);
```

Comment: What is $request->tokenId referred to?